# Call a javascript tag in a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems with my codes mostly because there are so many and so I was wondering if you can somehow use a `<script src =" url ">` " tag inside JavaScript code.

For example:

```html
<script>
  var num = 20;
  var nom2 = 50;
  if (num2 == num) {
    console.log("Fail");
  else {
    /* Code script here */
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by using *"script src =" url "> " tag inside a javascript*?

Comment: for example    <script>
      var num = 20;
      var nom2 = 50;
        if(num2 == num){
          console.log("Fail");
        else{
         <script src="https//:example.code.js"></script> 
         }
    <script>

Comment: You could start an AJAX call to read and evaluate https//:example.code.js